# Проблема работы с базой данных

Tags: c#, sql-server

Имеется база данных ELSdb подключенная в SQL Server. В App.config прописан путь. `DataSource=MILA-PC;Initial Catalog=ELSdb;Integrated Security=True`. Имеется таблица в БД в которой записан логин и пароль.
При запуске программа пишет неверный пароль или логин (ввод был верным). База данных ELSdb в SQL Server подключена и работает (активное подключение).

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: `программа пишет неверный пароль или логин (ввод был верным)` сами себе противоречите.

Comment: @tym32167, я ввела правильный пароль как в базе данных. я не понимаю почему так получается?

Comment: Если вы ввели правильный пароль, то почему оно пишет, что он неправильный?

Comment: В чём может быть причина? На этом сайте принято отвечать на вопросы предметно -- то есть вы показываете код, а мы говорим, что в коде вызывает такое поведение. Код вы не предоставили - поэтому обсуждать нечего. Как говорится, причин может быть множество: https://bash.im/quote/438821